# MySQLi error - same output twice

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

I found a certain problem. When I create a new table in my database, then I want to, of course, show the tables inside it. But if I create another table inside the database. Then my output suddenly increases (ex. created 1 table, created second table. Now I have 4 tables in total shown on the website even though I don't have 4 in my database).

Can anybody fix the code and explain?

```
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLES");
      while($tableName = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

                $table = $tableName[0];

                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'd197243_games'");

                $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$table."`";
                $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result3);

                $querys = "SELECT * FROM `".$table."` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
                $resulty = mysqli_query($conn, $querys);

                $rowsy = mysqli_fetch_row($resulty);

            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
      {

    //select * from table limit 1;
                $p = $row2[0];
                $s = $rows[0];
                $l = $rowsy[1];
                        echo "<div class='discussionTable'>
                            <div class='dcolumn' style='width: 60%; position: absolute; padding-left: 10px;'>
                                <b><h3 style='padding: 15px;'><a href='discussion_gaming_showarticle.php?sid=$table' style='color: white'>$table</a></b><br><p style='font-size: 13px'>Author: $p</p></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div style='padding-top: 10px;'>
                            <div class='dcolumn' style='width: 30%; float: right;'>
                                <p style='padding: 15px; line-height: 0px'>Total comments: $s</p>
                                <p style='padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 0px; line-height: 0px'>Last comment by: $l</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>";
            }
       }
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is no table creation code here.

Comment: I know there's not. It does not matter where I create the table, either from code or Phpmyadmin, it's still the same.

Comment: The outer while loop loops over all your tables, then $results2 gets all the tables from your database again.  You don't need the inner loop...or so it seems.

Comment: You're looping, one loop for each table.  `$table = $tableName[0];` never changes.

Comment: yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nested `while` loop. Your inner `while` loop displays the database tables in HTML, and your outer `while` loop loops through each table.

So, if you have two tables, there are two iterations of your outer loop, and two iterations of your inner loop *per* outer loop, meaning four iterations total of your inner loop and therefore four tables being displayed.

Your display loop should only run once. You could fix this by combining your queries into one using a join. This is considered better practice anyways.

Unfortunately, I don't know the names of your columns or your tables, so I can't help you write one. But I would suggest an `INNER JOIN` of some sort.

Or, if you don't care about best practices, then you can just remove the inner loop and just extract the data with `mysqli_fetch_row`. Your display code would be moved into the outer loop.

Comment: Deleted one loop and now runs perfectly. Thank you for you time and help. And also thank you everyone. This website is a miracle. Many answers in such a short time. Wow. I will accept your answer once it's possible.